# Why is Xcode 4 Preview 5 not resolving the crget() function when I include <sys/ucred.h>?

Tags: c, osx-snow-leopard, kernel

I am experimenting with the Mac OS X 10.6.5 kernel libraries.  Specifically, I am attempting to do a very simple call to the crget() function (please see: http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/ucred.h?v=DFBSD#L101 for function prototype).

The code is only:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/ucred.h>

// Main().

int main (void) {

   // Return a ucred struct from kernel for this process.
   struct ucred *processCredentials = crget();

   // Rest of code...

   return 0;
}
```

XCode reports:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_crget", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: I can't find any reference to this in Darwin. Are you sure it isn't specific to FreeBSD and DragonflyBSD?

Comment: Hi Ignacio.  It's referenced in the "Mac OS X Kernel Reference" document from Apple's Mac Developer reference library.  In PDF, it's page 26, with the subheading "Basic User Credentials".  It's likely from the FreeBSD portion of the kernel, as Google's of crget() return *BSD references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/security/security.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH206-DontLinkElementID_695):

> Note: Functions for working with basic user credential [sic] are not exported outside of the kernel, and thus are not generally available to kernel extensions.

So unless you're modifying the kernel proper, or using what may amount to an atrocious hack, you can't link against them.

Comment: Oh, duh!  I should have read farther before experimenting.  Thanks for the clarification and sorry for posting a dumb question.